# How do I get my label to stick to the top right of my landscape screen with CGPOINT in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uilabel

Firstly I'm new to swift and I'm trying to create a label that will show a value from my player class on the top right of the screen. How do I make a sticky label on the top right that will stay there as the user pans around the screen?

My end goal is to create something like this clash clans example:
[image: clash clans example]

I've created this so far and don't want it to be positioned in middle, Instead what I'm interested in is changing it's position to the side and stay there as the user scrolls.

```
func layoutScene() {
    scoreLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext-Bold"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 60.0 
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 1;
    addChild(scoreLabel)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - scoreLabel.frame.width - 16, y: frame.maxY - 16)
```

Comment: Hi Schaheer thanks for the response! I am getting an error "Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'bounds'" does that mean i'm missing something else?

Comment: Hey no problem! Sorry about that... I've fixed that. Check revised answer. Remove bounds

Comment: Oh awesome I saw your edit and its working. Is there anyway to make it sticky? Like when I pan around to stay in the corner?

Comment: Great! I'm assuming there is a scrollView behind this view... So what you can do is add the label view behind the scrollView. And set the scrollView background to clear color

Comment: ahhh thank you. I didn't have a scrollview lol, but I looked it up online and added it, That fixed it! thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have any resources that might be helpful to understand how the view controller works?

Comment: Don't mention it! Great (Y)

Comment: Read this blog... Hope it helps. https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5

Comment: this is bad advice with the scrollView.This is SpriteKit not UIKit. You wouldn't add a scrollView to your game. You would add an empty SKNode (ie. call it controlsLayer) and add it your scene. then when scrolling (via camera or manual movement) around you move the bottom layers but top SKNode stays in sight

Comment: This is not a good way to do it. You need to account for different aspect ratios and your scene size may end up chopping off some text.  Using UIKit with constraints will work better and will also allow your game engine to work better since it doesn’t need to traverse through static nodes that have no impact on game logic.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  and Ron. Yes actually you guys are right I was having some issues with the UIKit Scroll view. Instead with the CGPoint given by Schaheer I used  gameCamera.addChild(scoreLabel) and that fixed my problem

Comment: You would not use a scroll view at all.....  your scrolling should be the camera, but your static labels should be ui kit

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of that completely. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

To stick your lable on the top of the view:

1) You need to add transparent UIView on the top of your view.Set this view with leading and top constraint with supperView, give height, width & set UIColor as clear.

2)set your button into your transparent UIView & give appropriate constraint to it.

> Note: If you are using scrollView or any other view and trying to stick your button on it. Give the constraint to your transparent view with main view(self.view) so another subviews underneath your transparent view will stay free from it.

Comment: this is bad advice.This is SpriteKit not UIKit. You wouldn't add a UIView to your game. You would add an empty SKNode (ie. call it controlsLayer) and add it your scene. then when scrolling (via camera or manual movement) around you move the bottom layers but top SKNode stays in sight

Comment: @RonMyschuk this is actually good advice.   If this was 5 years ago I would agree, but the UIKit inclusion has gotten a lot better. Take anything static out of the scene tree.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon maybe if they were UIKit controls but why would you add SpriteKit controls to a UIView on top of SpriteKit scene

Comment: @RonMyschuk I will admit the answer needs a little better clarification to say to use UILabel instead of SKLabel